# Inheritance of Class Object after assignment Python

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, instances

So my problem is if I have the classes

```
class Source:

    def __init__(self):
        self.srcname = None
    @property    
    def __name__(self):
        sources = ['indeed','careerbuilder','glassdoor']
        if self.srcname is None:
            return KeyError("Invalid Source Name. Failed to set srcname")
        elif self.srcname not in sources:
            return KeyError("%s - Source invalid")
        else:
            return self.srcname
    @property
    def header(self):
        return dict(u=1)

class Other(Source):

    def __init__(self):
         Source.__init__(self)
         self.srcname = "mysource"

    def get(self):
         return self.header

class Again(Source):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get(self):
        return self.srcname
```

I tried...

```
print(Other().get())  ## Works
>>> {"u":1}
print(Again().get()) ## Failed

##Traceback (most recent call last):
##  File "~/Desktop/_source.py", line 69, in <module>
##    print(Again().get())
##  File "~/Desktop/_source.py", line 66, in get
##    return self.srcname
##AttributeError: 'Again' object has no attribute 'srcname'
```

Basically, I want a unified parser class that will inherit source name after it has already been assigned from another class.

Comment: Show us the code where ```...it didn't work...``` and the Traceback if there was one..

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I just edited it. Hope this is better.

Comment: ```Again().get()``` doesn't throw an AttributeError with the code you posted.  It still isn't clear what problem you are seeking help with.  Maybe read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this :

```
class Data(Source):  
    def __init__(self):
        Source.__init__(self)
```

keep this:

```
class Data(Source):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
```

because

```
super().__init__()
```

indicates inheritance(constructor) from the parent class. You can mention arguments in super().**init**() constructor.

for further clarification regarding class and inheritance refer this
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php